# Nexus index of Maven Central is not up to date (new installation)

Tags: maven, clojure, nexus, maven-central

I have a brand new installation of Sonatype Nexus that I intend to use to proxy Maven Central and other repositories. Everything seemed to be working well until I wanted to get the latest version of clojure-maven-plugin from com.theoryinpractise. From Eclipse, I could only see releases up to version 1.3.8 when I know that later versions exist.

I tried searching search.maven.org and that confirmed that releases 1.3.9 and 1.3.10 are indeed available in the central repository.

I've logged into Sonatype Nexus using the web interface and tried "Browse Index" for the central repo and it only lists releases up to 1.3.8. However, using the "Browse Remote" tab for the same repo shows the releases up to 1.3.10.

I've tried everything I can think of to get the index up to date ("Download Remote Indexes" is set to true and I've selected Expire Cache, Repair Index, Update Index). My Nexus installation is only 4 days old so I'm not sure why at least the 1.3.9 release which is 3 months old would not be reflected in the intially downloaded index.

I would be grateful for any ideas on what to try next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reported the issue to Sonatype. It appears to be a known issue with Maven Central:

> "I'm seeing the same thing here, there seems to be a pattern of some recent artifacts being missing from central's index.  I've updated the issue I filed for this:
>
> https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-201
>
> Note that search indexes are not used by Maven builds, so you will still be able to access this artifact from your build.  Also, once it has been downloaded through Nexus it will show up in the search index."

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the [download of remote indexes](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-manage-repo.html). By default this feature is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark mentioned you should set the flag to download the remote index to true for all proxy repositories that publish an index.

In addition you should create a scheduled task that will download the indexes for all repositories in regular intervals to ensure your indexes are up to date and contain all artifacts that became available since the last download.

Comment: Manfred and @Mark, thanks for your answers, but I guess I should have made it clear that I have already set "Download Remote Indexes" to true (I'll edit the original post). I do have an index but it's apparently not up to date. I have also already set up a scheduled task to re-download indexes which apparently ran successfully 2 days ago. And just to re-iterate, as my installation is only 4 (now 5) days old, it's unclear why 3-month old artifacts would not be in the index.

Comment: Maybe create an issue within Nexus so that the developers can look at it with the logs that get automatically attached or ask on the mailing list instead of here..

Comment: Good suggestion. I had already done that a few hours ago and I've just posted their reply as an answer.